# El problema el valor con fecha(datepicker) en codeigniter

Tags: php, bootstrap, codeigniter

tengo bootstrap-datepicker, cuando clic con input y mostra la fecha. viste mal año "Noviembre 0)" y falta este año 2017. no se como solucional.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: Consulta sql sdfsdfsdfsdf]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No te sale error en la consola? Esa fecha es inválida para inicializar un objeto `Date` en javascript. Yo probaría dejar el valor en blanco cuando la fecha sean puros ceros o sea null. De esa manera el datepicker mostraría por defecto la fecha de hoy

Comment: Hola @Diego Sagredo, al parecer es algo por defecto, ya que a mi tambien me sucede lo mismo.